# Map control WP8 - Hide the actual map, keep layers?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

How do I deactivate the actual map view (ex, the streets, terrain but keep a layer active? I am doing this to show weather radar in my app's background without a map...

Answer (score 0):

If using the older "Bing" based map control (marked as obsolete) in Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps then it's possible to remove (and add map layers).

To iterate through all map layers and remove them one at a time:

```
for (var i = Map.Children.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    MapTileLayer tileLayer = Map.Children[i] as MapTileLayer;
    if (tileLayer != null)
    {
        Map.Children.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

You'll need to play around to work out exactly what map layers you need to remove to achieve the effect you want.

Even though this older map control has been superseded in WP8 the newer control doesn't seem to support the same flexibility with layers.

BTW: The map control available in WP8.1 projects might allow good flexibility with map layers.